# xamarin froms listview selecteditem not update value of view - mmvm

Tags: forms, listview, xamarin, mvvm, selecteditem

I need in a listview when the user select a row, show a item of the row. This item is visible = true, but when selected item i need change to false.

MyObject Class:

```
  public class MyObject
    {
        public int IdObject { get; set; }
        public string ObjectName { get; set; }
        public bool? CirculoVisible { get; set; } = true;
    }
```

My xaml:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyObjects}" 
SelectedItem="{Binding ObjectSeleccionado, Mode=TwoWay}"  >
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
           <ViewCell>
                  <Label Text="prueba" IsVisible="{Binding CirculoVisible ,Mode=TwoWay}" />
                  <Label Text="{Binding ObjectName}" TextColor="Black" />
           </ViewCell>
       </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

My viewmodel ( MVVM ) . The app enter here, but nothing appears and the item not change. 
The class has the new value but the property not change.

```
    private MyObject _objectseleccionado;
    public MyObject ObjectSeleccionado
    {
        get
        {
            return _objectseleccionado;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_objectseleccionado != value && value != null)
            {
                value.ObjectName = "Pepito";
                value.CirculoVisible = false;

                _objectseleccionado = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ObjectSeleccionado"));



            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Setter
try this

```
set
    {
        if (_objectseleccionado != value && value != null)
        {
            _objectseleccionado = value;
            _objectseleccionado.ObjectName = "Pepito";
            _objectseleccionado.CirculoVisible = false;


            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ObjectSeleccionado"));



        }
```

Comment: Nothing. I debug and enter into setter but not change.

Comment: propertychanged event will be triggered and reflected into UI when your bindable object is derived from INotifyPropertyChanged Interface.
Are you using it?

Comment: Yes, I'am using InotifyPropertyChanged.